# What controls timezone to GMT offset mapping in WebLogic?

Tags: java, date, weblogic, dst

I am facing an unusual problem.

An application deploying in Production on Oracle WebLogic has started exhibiting a bug.  Dates that should be printing out as, e.g., `24 Mar 00:00:00 EDT 2020` are printing out as `23 Mar 23:00:00 EST 2020`.

The other WebLogic server logs, not from our application, are also printing in EST (Eastern Standard Time) instead of EDT (Eastern Daylight Time).

This is only happening in Production.

The timezone, which the application dumps to its log, is correct in all environments (i.e., "America/New_York").  I checked the `$JRE_HOME/lib/tzdb.dat` files in both environments and they are identical.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: I would have expected that to be controlled by the JVM’s default time zone setting. And the bug to be caused by some program in the WebLogic having changed that (every program can do that). Do you know whether the `America/New_York` printed is the JVM’s time zone?

Comment: I thought of that, but there was only one other program deployed recently and I didn't see anything specific to timezones in the changes.  But its an Oracle ADF application, so something could be going on deep in the bowels of ADF, I guess.

Comment: To answer your question, America/New_York is printed out as user.timezone.  That's all the log includes about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The JVM default time zone setting has been changed

It’s a guess, but a fully consistent one. The dates and times that are printed with time zone abbreviation (EST or EDT) most probably use the JVM’s default time zone. So the setting of the default time zone has been changed in your production WebLogic server. Any program running in the server can do that. Even a program running outside WebLogic in the same JVM can if there is one. At any time.

The default time zone is set from the system property user.timezone on startup (or the first time a program in the JVM does anything with a time zone, I am not sure). Changing the JVM’s default time zone later on does *not* work back on the system property. For a brief demonstration:

```
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/New_York");

    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Atikokan"));

    System.out.println("TimeZone.getDefault(): " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    System.out.println("user.timezone: " + System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
    System.out.println("Example java.util.Date: " + new Date());
```

Running this snippet on my computer gave the following output:

> ```
> TimeZone.getDefault(): America/Atikokan
> user.timezone: America/New_York
> Example java.util.Date: Thu Mar 19 14:18:03 EST 2020
> ```

You notice that `user.timezone` prints as `America/New_York`, yet the last line mentions `EST`, so doesn’t agree with `America/New_York`, which would have implied `EDT` if I am not mistaken.

PS Usually I would discourage the use of the `TimeZone` class altogether since it is poorly designed and long outdated. I needed it for this demonstration since java.time, the modern Java date and time API, does not offer an option to change the time zone setting of the JVM (that I know of). Maybe they made a wise choice by not including it since — as you can see — doing that can easily cause confusion.

Comment: You may be right.  I'll upvote but cannot accept until I isolate the problem though.  Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Thanks for upvoting. I agree, you should not only do your own analysis, you should also wait a couple of days and see if other answers are posted before you accept any answer. After you accept one, your question will get less attention, it's not what you need right now.